# Why use a plane if we already have a box in three.js?

Tags: graphics, three.js, 3d, data-visualization

I have a 3d visualization that I'd like to put on surface. I could put it on a box that I could shape like a plane. I'd like the shape to have a bit of thickness, kind of like the shape of a book. But then I noticed there's already a plane geometry.

So I was wondering why is there a plane if one could just use a box and shape it anyway they want to?

https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/BoxGeometry
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/PlaneGeometry

Comment: Less amount of vertices? Thus less amount of faces etc.

Comment: Planes and boxes are fundamentally different things. Just because you can one make look like the other does not mean that you always should. Appearance isn't everything.

Comment: @NicoSchertler isn't a plane a box with 0 height. what's the difference? and when should I use one over the other.

Comment: No. A box is a closed polyhedron. It does not have a boundary. A plane does. If you just scale a box to height zero, you will get four degenerate faces and two faces that overlap (and have opposite orientation). As prisoner mentioned, a box has more data to process for the GPU. In practice, just choose the primitive that fits your purpose. I can't imagine a case where that wouldn't be obvious.